# How to make a Hamburgermenu swipeable the easiest way?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

Neko here,

I looked around but i never found a solution for this, so I ask here now: What is the easiest way to create a swipeable Splitview?

I tried out nearly everything, but nothing helps :/

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/SwipeableSplitView

Comment: Yes, i tried this many times, but i dont understand it. I am still trying to figure it out how it works and how I can implement it into my own project...